# Convergence of filterbases

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers. It is not hard to show that $\mathcal{F}=\{A\subset\mathbb{N} : \mathbb{N}\setminus A \text{ is finite }\}$ is a filter on $\mathbb{N}$. Actually my question is about the following theorem.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, $x_{0}$ be fixed and $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$ with $f(n)=x_{n}$.( for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$) Then, $f(\mathcal{F})\to x_{0}$ if and only if $x_{n}\to x_{0}$

I know that $f(\mathcal{F})$ is a filter base for a filter on $X$. What does “ $f(\mathcal{F})\to x_{0}$” mean? Does it mean this filter base $f(\mathcal{F})$ contains all of neighborhoods of $x_{0}$?

Also we do not know if $f$ is surjective.

Here is my attempt for the right side. Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $x_{0}$. Since $f(\mathcal{F})\to x_{0}$, then $U\in f(\mathcal{F})$. So there exists $A\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $f(A)=\{x_{n} :n\in A\}=U$. Since $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ is finite, then $\{n: x_{n}\notin U\}$ is at most finite. Consequently $x_{n}\to x_{0}$.

Is my attempt true? If so, for the other side would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$f(\mathcal F)=\{B\subset X\mid f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal F\}$ is more than a filter base. It is a filter on $X.$

A filter is said to converge to $a$ if it contains every neighborhood of $a.$

$$f(\mathcal F)\to a\iff\mathcal V(a)\subset f(\mathcal F)\iff\forall V\in\mathcal V(a)\quad\Bbb N\setminus f^{-1}(V)\text{ is finite }$$$$\iff\forall V\in\mathcal V(a)\quad\exists N\in\Bbb N\quad\forall n\ge N\quad f(n)\in V\iff x_n\to a.$$

Comment: I suppose $f(\mathcal{F})=\{f(A): A\in\mathcal{F}\}$. Are they different ones ? @AnneBauval

Comment: The classical definition of $f(\mathcal F)$ is in my answer. This set is different from what you just wrote.

Comment: I see, then the question meant by “$f(\mathcal{F})” is what you wrote, right ? @AnneBauval

Comment: Exactly. "Your" $f(\mathcal F)$ is a subset of the classical one. This is why your proof for the "right side" works. But the converse only holds for the classical definition, I think.

Comment: Now, my last "I think" becomes "I'm sure": e.g. $X=\Bbb R,$ $x_n=\frac1n\to0.$ Your $f(\mathcal F)$ is a set of *at most countable* subsets of $X.$ It does not contain all the neighborhoods of $0,$ it even contains none!

Comment: Why you say “none”? @AnneBauval

Comment: Because every neighborhood of $0$ is uncountable.

Comment: So, $f(\mathcal{F})$ must exactly be understood as you wrote ? @AnneBauval

Comment: Yes, this is the usual definition, and with that definition your equivalence is proved.

Comment: Thank you very much, after you had Said it, I handled @AnneBruval

Comment: However, may be "your" $f(\mathcal F)$ is a base for "the usual one".

Comment: it is actually, there is a proposition About it I guess @AnneBruval